# http post request get SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android

I'm trying to configure an HTTP POST request, but I get `SocketTimeoutException` all the times.
Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

```
int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 60000;  // = 60 seconds
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(URL_STRING); 

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(builder.toString());

request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jobj.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: may be it's just your server not answering ?

Comment: Is your server listening on default port?. If not. Have you specified the port?. Is your server answering petitions correctly on web browser?. What kind of response are you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this code. It will help you to understand handling almost all basic HttpClient exception.
    try {

```
    // check for request method
    if (method == "POST") {
        // request method is POST
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        // new
        HttpParams httpParameters = httpPost.getParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
        // established.
        int timeoutConnection = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        // new
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } else if (method == "GET") {
        // request method is GET
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        // new
        HttpParams httpParameters = httpGet.getParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
        // established.
        int timeoutConnection = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        // new
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    }

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new Exception("Unsupported encoding error.");
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    throw new Exception("Client protocol error.");
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    throw new Exception("Sorry, socket timeout.");
} catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
    throw new Exception("Sorry, connection timeout.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new Exception("I/O error(May be server down).");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to set socket timeout.
Remove this line:

HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);